# Find an expression for a sequence of numbers ordered within an interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I have an interval say, $[x_{n-1}, x_n]$. Within this interval, I have two other numbers, say $y_i$ and $z_j$. I want to do some calculations within this given interval. I will give an illustration below. Suppose for  $n=1$ I have the following:

(i)  $x_0 \lt y_1 \lt z_1 \lt y_2 \lt z_2 \lt x_1$

(ii) $ x_0 \lt z_1 \lt y_1 \lt z_2 \lt y_2 \lt x_1 $

(iii) $ x_0 \lt z_1 \lt z_2 \lt y_1 \lt y_2 \lt x_1 $

(iv) $ x_0 \lt z_1 \lt y_1 \lt y_2 \lt z_2 \lt x_1 $

(v) $ x_0 \lt y_1 \lt z_1 \lt z_2 \lt y_2 \lt x_1 $

---

Let $k$ be a function. Then in the case of (i), we have

(I) $k(x_0) ( y_1-x_0) + k(y_1) (z_1 - y_1) + k(z_1)(y_2 - z_1) + k(y_2)(z_2 - y_2) + k(z_2) ( x_1 - z_2) $

(II) $ k(x_0) (z_1-x_0) + k(z_1)(y_1 -z_1) + k(y_1)(z_2-y_1) + k(z_2)(y_2-z_2) + k(y_2)(x_1-y_2)~.. $

similarly for (iii), (iv) and (v).  How do I write a general formula or expression for such an operation? The numbers $y_i, z_j$ can be ordered arbitrarily between the fixed numbers $x_{n-1}$ and $x_n$.

Comment: There may be a sixth option of (vi) $x_0 \lt y_1 \lt y_2  \lt z_1 \lt z_2 \lt x_1$

Comment: @Henry You absolutely right. However, I'm looking at the scenario where you can any finite number of $y_i$'s and $z_j$'s arranged in any order between $x_{n-1}$ and $x_n$.

Comment: Why not just re-name :  Let $\{x_n,x_{n+1},y_{1,n},y_{2,n},z_{1,n},z_{2,n}\}$ $=\{a_{n,j}:1\leq j\leq 6\}$  where  $a_{n,j}<a_{n,j+1}$ for $1\leq j\leq 5,$  and let the expression involving $k$ be $\sum_{j=1}^5k(a_{n,j})(a_{n,j+1}-a_{n,j})$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks for your comment. Any ideas on how to generalize?